# Dissolving/merging polygons taking into account area of intersection

Tags: qgis, merge, dissolve

How in QGIS do I dissolve/merge polygons taking into account the area of intersection?

For example, if area of intersection less then 15% of polygon area then operation should't apply.

Answer (score 6):

It may be done using SQL through creating a virtual layer or querying your layer in db manager:

1. Resave your data into geopackage or spartialite format. We'll need
   unique id column (in my case it's just "id").
2. Create a virtual layer based on your layer with the following
   definition:

```
/* Intersecting all features with overlapping area > 15% */

    with intersection as (
        select 
            a.id,
            st_union(st_union(a.geometry, b.geometry)) geometry
        from tmp a
        join tmp b
            on a.id < b.id
                and st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
                and st_area(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry)) >= st_area(a.geometry) * 0.15
                and st_area(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry)) >= st_area(b.geometry) * 0.15
    )

    /* Select all features that were not intersected and join datasets */
    select
        a.id,
        a.geometry
    from tmp a 
    cross join intersection b
    where not st_within(a.geometry, b.geometry)
    union
    select * from intersection
```

You may also query your layer through dbmanager if it's complicated enough (virtual layers area slow)

[image]